# Python Pandas: How to read only first n rows of CSV files in?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, file-io

I have a very large data set and I can't afford to read the entire data set in. So, I'm thinking of reading only one chunk of it to train but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

If you only want to read the first 999,999 (non-header) rows:

```
read_csv(..., nrows=999999)
```

If you only want to read rows 1,000,000 ... 1,999,999

```
read_csv(..., skiprows=1000000, nrows=999999)
```

***nrows*** : int, default None Number of rows of file to read. Useful for
reading pieces of large files*

***skiprows*** : list-like or integer
Row numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of rows to skip (int) at the start of the file

and for large files, you'll probably also want to use chunksize:

***chunksize*** : int, default None
Return TextFileReader object for iteration

[pandas.io.parsers.read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Note that if your file has colum names in row 0, skiprows takes a list or range. `read_csv('path', ..., skiprows=[1, 1000000], nrows=999999)` or `read_csv('path', ..., skiprows=range(1, 1000000), nrows=999999)`

Answer (score 3):

`chunksize=` is a very useful argument because the output of `read_csv` after passing it is an iterator, so you can call the `next()` function on it to get the specific chunk you want without straining your memory. For example, to get the first `n` rows, you can use:

```py
chunks = pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=n)
df = next(chunks)
```

For example, if you have a time-series data and you want to make the first 700k rows the train set and the remainder test set, then you can do so by:

```py
chunks = pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=700_000)
train_df = next(chunks)
test_df = next(chunks)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Pandas, you can use csv library and to limit row readed with interaction break.

For example, I needed to read a list of files stored in *csvs* list to get the only the header.

```
for csvs in result:
    csvs = './'+csvs
    with open(csvs,encoding='ANSI', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        count=0
        for row in csv_reader:
            if count:
                break;
```