# How can I get the first 100 lines of this CSV without reading all the data

Tags: pandas

I have a very large CSV file, and my memory can't read the whole CSV at all. How can I get the first 100 lines of this CSV without reading all the data

Comment: There's an option `nrows` in `pd.read_csv`. You can try `pd.read_csv('file.csv', nrows=100)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: How to read only first n rows of CSV files in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853553/python-pandas-how-to-read-only-first-n-rows-of-csv-files-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

first100 = pd.read_csv("someCoolData.csv", nrows=100)
```

This will read only the first 100 rows into a data frame from a given csv file.

For further explanation of what's going on refer to:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Thank you. I also considered this method at the beginning, but I can't be sure that panda reads the specified number of rows after reading the CSV into memory. I just tested this situation, and I found that panda only reads the specified number of rows into memory, not all of them.